# Conditionally inserting a set number of rows of preceeding dates

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working on a data set that looks like the following:

```
   ID    Date         Diar    wt    ht
   1     1/11/2012    1       23    15
   1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19
   2     2/23/2014    1       17    22
   2     2/28/2016    1       20    30
   2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32
```

I need to insert 6 rows of dates prior to the date in the `Date` column if `Diar == 1`. When I insert these dates, I need to ensure the `ID` number also gets carried through, but not the `Diar`, `wt`, or `ht` values.

Ideally the data set will look like the following:

```
   ID    Date         Diar    wt    ht
   1     1/05/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/06/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/07/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/08/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/09/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/10/2012    NA      NA    NA
   1     1/11/2012    1       23    15
   1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19
   2     2/17/2014    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/18/2014    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/19/2014    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/20/2014    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/21/2014    NA      NA    NA       
   2     2/22/2014    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/23/2014    1       17    22
   2     2/22/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/23/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/24/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/25/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/26/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/27/2016    NA      NA    NA
   2     2/28/2016    1       20    30
   2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32
```

Any direction on how to do this is greatly appreciated. I have searched through stack overflow to find similar posts on how to insert a specific number of dates conditionally, but have not been successful. If you see a post that addresses this that I missed, please post it.

Comment: @akrun thanks for pointing this out. I just edited this problem

Comment: @akrun fixed! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution (since post is tagged with `data.table`):

```
# Format date properly:
DS[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")]

DS[, 
   if (!is.na(Diar) && Diar == 1) {
     newrows <- data.table(ID = rep(ID, 6), Date = Date - 6:1)
     rbindlist(list(newrows, .SD), fill = TRUE)
   } else {
     .SD
   },
   by = 1:nrow(DS)
   ][, !"seq_len"]


#     ID       Date Diar wt ht
#  1:  1 2012-01-05   NA NA NA
#  2:  1 2012-01-06   NA NA NA
#  3:  1 2012-01-07   NA NA NA
#  4:  1 2012-01-08   NA NA NA
#  5:  1 2012-01-09   NA NA NA
#  6:  1 2012-01-10   NA NA NA
#  7:  1 2012-01-11    1 23 15
#  8:  1 2015-01-23   NA 27 19
#  9:  2 2014-02-17   NA NA NA
# 10:  2 2014-02-18   NA NA NA
# 11:  2 2014-02-19   NA NA NA
# 12:  2 2014-02-20   NA NA NA
# 13:  2 2014-02-21   NA NA NA
# 14:  2 2014-02-22   NA NA NA
# 15:  2 2014-02-23    1 17 22
# 16:  2 2016-02-22   NA NA NA
# 17:  2 2016-02-23   NA NA NA
# 18:  2 2016-02-24   NA NA NA
# 19:  2 2016-02-25   NA NA NA
# 20:  2 2016-02-26   NA NA NA
# 21:  2 2016-02-27   NA NA NA
# 22:  2 2016-02-28    1 20 30
# 23:  2 2017-03-17   NA 25 32
#     ID       Date Diar wt ht
```

Data

```
library(data.table)
DS <- fread(
  "ID    Date         Diar    wt    ht
   1     1/11/2012    1       23    15
   1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19
   2     2/23/2014    1       17    22
   2     2/28/2016    1       20    30
   2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32"
)
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted so far create the missing rows piecewise and row-bind the intermediate results afterwards.

Here is a different, more "SQL-like" approach which creates the final result by *joining* the original dataset with an expanded ("completed") data.table:

```
DT[, Date := lubridate::mdy(Date)][]
tmp <- DT[, .(ID, Date = seq(from = Date - 6 * isTRUE(Diar == 1), to = Date, by = "1 day")), 
   by = seq_along(ID)][, seq_along := NULL][]
DT[tmp, on = .(ID, Date)]
```

> ```
>     ID       Date Diar wt ht
>  1:  1 2012-01-05   NA NA NA
>  2:  1 2012-01-06   NA NA NA
>  3:  1 2012-01-07   NA NA NA
>  4:  1 2012-01-08   NA NA NA
>  5:  1 2012-01-09   NA NA NA
>  6:  1 2012-01-10   NA NA NA
>  7:  1 2012-01-11    1 23 15
>  8:  1 2015-01-23   NA 27 19
>  9:  2 2014-02-17   NA NA NA
> 10:  2 2014-02-18   NA NA NA
> 11:  2 2014-02-19   NA NA NA
> 12:  2 2014-02-20   NA NA NA
> 13:  2 2014-02-21   NA NA NA
> 14:  2 2014-02-22   NA NA NA
> 15:  2 2014-02-23    1 17 22
> 16:  2 2016-02-22   NA NA NA
> 17:  2 2016-02-23   NA NA NA
> 18:  2 2016-02-24   NA NA NA
> 19:  2 2016-02-25   NA NA NA
> 20:  2 2016-02-26   NA NA NA
> 21:  2 2016-02-27   NA NA NA
> 22:  2 2016-02-28    1 20 30
> 23:  2 2017-03-17   NA 25 32
>     ID       Date Diar wt ht
> ```

The result is in line with expected result and with OP's requirement:

> When I insert these dates, I need to ensure the `ID` number also gets
>   carried through, but not the `Diar`, `wt`, or `ht` values.

#### Explanation

1. First, the `Date` column is coerced to class `Date` because we need to perform date arithmetic.
2. `tmp` is a data.table which contains the completed `ID` / `Date` combinations. For each row of `DT` a `Date` sequence is created which is either one day long if `Diar` is `NA` or 7 days long if `Diar` equals `1`. The trick is to use arithmetic instead of an `if` clause.
   `isTRUE(Diar == 1)` is used because it includes a check for `NA`.  The helper column `seq_along` is removed as it is no longer needed.
   So, `tmp` becomes:

```
    ID       Date
 1:  1 2012-01-05
 2:  1 2012-01-06
 3:  1 2012-01-07
 4:  1 2012-01-08
 5:  1 2012-01-09
 6:  1 2012-01-10
 7:  1 2012-01-11
 8:  1 2015-01-23
 9:  2 2014-02-17
10:  2 2014-02-18
11:  2 2014-02-19
12:  2 2014-02-20
13:  2 2014-02-21
14:  2 2014-02-22
15:  2 2014-02-23
16:  2 2016-02-22
17:  2 2016-02-23
18:  2 2016-02-24
19:  2 2016-02-25
20:  2 2016-02-26
21:  2 2016-02-27
22:  2 2016-02-28
23:  2 2017-03-17
    ID       Date
```

3. Finally, the original data.table `DT` is right-joined with the completed cases `tmp`.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
   ID    Date         Diar    wt    ht
   1     1/11/2012    1       23    15
   1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19
   2     2/23/2014    1       17    22
   2     2/28/2016    1       20    30
   2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32")
```